# Python, Having problems with .append() method

Tags: python, list

I'm using anaconda Python 3 notebook. And When I Try to append anything to a list, my pc goes mad. It gets slow, the RAM goes to 95% and it just wont work anymore. But i noticed somethin, the problem only occurs when I use a for statement. and if I use slice brackets I dont have that problem, so thi would be like this:

Problem:

```
for element in anylist:
       anylist.append('whatever')
```

(So far, i think this one never stop working and it may be causing some truobles. I dont really know)

No problem:

```
for element in anylist[:]:
      anylist.append('whatever')
```

Another detail: All this started right before I imported the String module, and the Os module. But now it happens every time i write single code.

Python is in 64 bits as it has to be in my case.
If you could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: the first example runs forever because you are constantly adding to the list you're looping through, the second example loops through a copy of `anylist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example can be translated as:

`while there is something more in anylist add whatever to the end`

*which means the list will grow until the system crashes.*

So it will never end. The second translates as:

```
for the number of items in anylist add whatever to the end of the list.
```

*So will double the length of the list.*

Hence python is doing exactly what you are telling it to do, (which I suspect is not what you think you are doing).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know it was a silly mistake, i guess thats why my question got a -2. I´m new here so I´m sorry if this was an already answered question or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
for element in range(len(anylist)):
    anylist.append('something')
```